# Mapping earth texture problem

Tags: texturing

I have a problem with earth texture mapping to an UV sphere as can be also seen by the photo below.
[image]

The mapping properties are as follows:

[image]

I have tried multiple combination of the properties but nothing could solve my problem. Do you have any idea why it shows like that?

Comment: Did you unwrap the sphere?

Comment: I tried it, and it seems that I had done something different from the tutorial. Thanks :)